# Is it bad practice to directly alter the state variable in a useState hook if I don't want the component to re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [activeObjects, setActiveObjects] = useState([]);
```

I am using the activeObjects array to map out a set of div elements. I understand that if I want to add or remove an item from the list, I want to use the setActiveObjects function to re-render the component so the user sees the new changes.

However, I've found many cases where I want to change properties of various objects in the activeObjects array without re-rendering the component. These properties would have no immediate use, they just contain information that will be needed later.

Is it bad practice to directly alter a property of an object in activeObjects such as `activeObjects[0].someData = "newData"`in this case?

Comment: Yes, it is bad practice. If you can give some more details about what use case is motivating you to consider this, we might be able to suggest some alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React documentation states that ["you shouldn’t change objects that you hold in the React state directly"](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state). There's [a section](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state#why-is-mutating-state-not-recommended-in-react) that gives some reasons not to mutate your objects.

React uses shallow comparison (equality by reference) to determine if the state has changed, so an object mutation is effectively invisible to React since the object reference doesn't change.

That being said, technically nothing stops you from modifying objects directly. It's a non-standard practice, however, so it could introduce unexpected behavior and make your code less maintainable in the future.

There might be some unique situations where mutating objects is reasonable, but you probably shouldn't do it in most cases. Normally, I wouldn't expect to see a mutation like this, so if you absolutely have to do it, you could consider documenting it clearly in your code.