# What are the problems with modifying a useState variable directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of data that is instantiated as a 'useState':

```
const [data, setData] = useState([...]);
```

I want to modify one entry of 'data'. Sticking to react conventions, I would probably do this:

```
d = data.copy();
d[index] = newValue;
setData(d);
```

However, seems like I could simply do `data[index] = newValue` and modify the array directly.

Are there any disadvantages to this latter, more direct approach? It seems much more elegant but also contradicts useState conventions.

EDIT: For anyone looking I found this page for a general overview: https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it bad practice to directly alter the state variable in a useState hook if I don't want the component to re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75763566/is-it-bad-practice-to-directly-alter-the-state-variable-in-a-usestate-hook-if-i)

Comment: The disadvantage of the latter is that it won't work if you need reliable re-rendering. There are multiple ways to make things **look** like you're modifying it directly but actually aren't. There are loads of resources answering this question, though, both here and on the web.

Comment: @Jai248 The thread you linked is helpful and the point about re-rendering is certainly relevant, but I am interested in a more general discussion of states as they pertain to other potential issues as well.

Comment: From a FP (functional programming) perspective (and React principles are heavily influenced by FP), mutating a value is the exact opposite of elegant. More practically, anything that utilizes a dependency array (`useEffect`, `useCallback`, `useMemo`) will fail to work correctly if you are mutating your values instead of replacing them with new, updated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, when you call `setData` with the same array reference as before, React may skip rerendering (causing changes to `data` to not be reflected) since it can assume that the state will not be modified.

See the following example:

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([1,2,3]);
  return <div>
    <p>Data: {JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
    <button onClick={() => {
      data[1] = 10;
      setData(data);
    }}>Change without copy</button>
    <button onClick={() => setData(data.map((x, i) => i === 1 ? 11 : x))}>
      Change with copy
    </button>
  </div>
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```